# A Nice Problem about relation between numbers in two sets.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, graph-theory

Consider two sets A and B. We call two sets Quality-AB if the product of two members from set A is equal to the product of two members of the set B.

Show that we can find a sequence to produce integers with Quality-AB given A and B are disjoint.

Comment: Are the sets $A=\{1,6\}$, $B=\{2,3\}$ an example of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Choose a prime $p$.  Let $A$ consist of all odd integral powers of $p$ and $B$ consist of all even integral powers of $p$.  If we take $p=2$ we have $$A=\{\ldots \frac 1{32},\frac 18,\frac 12,2,8,32,\ldots\}\\B=\{\ldots \frac 1{16},\frac 14,1,4,16,\ldots\}$$  Any product of two elements of A can be matched with a product of two elements of B and vice versa.  It does not matter if the two elements must be distinct or not.

Comment: Yeah sorry ... I had understood it to mean that the product of two elements of $B$ to be an element of $A$ and vice versa ... Your solution is sound ... I had hoped you had not noticed my misunderstanding.

Comment: Sorry Sorry SorrY Sorry, Your Solution is Not correct As Per Your Logic Given in comment. Actully I am confused that moment. No No i am not saying it

Comment: Actually I mean ab=cd if a and b belongs to A and c and d belongs to B

Comment: I don't understand your series of four comments at all.  I believe you can pick any two elements of A, multiply them, and find two elements of B to multiply to get the same product.  You do not specify whether the two elements need to be distinct or not.  Either way, there is a case of two elements of B that have a product you cannot produce from A, either $1,1$ if repetition is allowed or $1,p^2$ if repetition is not, but your question did not require that direction.  We can solve that by taking the powers to include negative ones.  You did not specify that all the entries must be integers

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the OP wants the disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ to consist of positive integers, and, consequently, that the "Quality-AB" condition is that for any pair of *distinct* elements $a$ and $a'$ in $A$ there are *distinct* elements $b$ and $b'$ in $B$ such that $aa'=bb'$ and vice versa. (I say "consequently" because if, say, $a$ is the overall *minimal* element in $A\cup B$, there are no elements $b$ and $b'$ such that $a^2=bb'$.)

Let

$$A=\{1\}\cup\{2^m3^n: mn\gt0\land2\mid(m+n)\}=\{1,6,24,36,54,144,216,324\ldots\}$$

and

$$B=\{2,3\}\cup\{2^m3^n:mn\gt0\land2\not\mid(m+n)\}=\{2,3,12,18,48,72,108,162,\ldots\}$$

It's easy to see that the product of any two elements of $A$ is either of the form $2b$ or $3b$, while the product of any two elements of $B$ is of the form $1a$.

Clearly you can substitute any two coprime numbers for $2$ and $3$.